# ROS Answers SE migration: Export error

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think I might have screwed up something in the environment variable. Is there anyway to remove this, because I couldn't find any help to get rid of this.

```
bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `/home/ubunturtle/ros_workspace': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `/home/ubunturtle/ros_workspace:/home/ubunturtle/ros_workspace:/opt/ros/fuerte/share:/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `/home/ubunturtle/ros_workspace': not a valid identifier
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37426/export-error/) by [RJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/2492/rj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 48 on 2012-06-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2012-06-27**:
Looks like a typo in an export command. We could provide you better help if you mention what command/file is generating that output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

check your .bashrc file. it's in your home folder (hidden file)

---

Originally posted by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) with karma: 2268 on 2012-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/2492/rj/) on 2012-06-27**:
Thanks a lot, managed to remove some stuff in the file. Now the export errors are gone.